# Latex stopped creating a bibliography after updating the system

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I use vim with with [vim-latexsuite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) and TexLive.
I use the .sty and .cls files, respectively the whole package date 2012-05-10  from the university of Hagenberg [Link to zip package](http://staff.fh-hagenberg.at/burger/diplomarbeit/index.html).

Till yesterday everything works like a charm which means that the document including the bibliography was build as intended.

Today I updated my notebook to vim 7.3, vim-latexsuite 20121118-1 and texlive 2012.28273-1.

I tried to compile my main file but the document doesn't either show a bibliography  nor references in the text. I have no idea why the bibliography cannot be resolved.

I devided the information I have into two sections.

In section 1 I try to show the relevant parts of my main, [sty] and cls document.

In section 2 I try to show the relevant parts of the log files.

// Section 1
/ main-file

```
\documentclass[bachelor,german]{hgbthesis}
\AddBibFile{literatur.bib}  % Angabe der BibTeX-Datei; is a wrapper for \addbibresource defined in .cls

\begin{document}

\include{cha1}
\include{cha2}

\MakeBibliography{Quellenverzeichnis}  %defined in .cls

\end{document}
```

/ .cls-file (hgbthesis.cls) - extract

```
\usepackage{csquotes}   % recommended for biblatex
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}[2011/05/12]
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{sortcites=true,defernumbers=true,isbn=false,doi=false}
\newcommand{\MakeBibliography}[2][]{
% opt. arg (#1): optional argument "nosplit" to get a 1-piece bibliography
% req. arg (#2): main title of bibliography
\clearpage
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{nosplit}}%
    {% create a single bibliography with all entries:
        \printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title={#2}]
        \begin{bibhyphenation}  
        \printbibliography[heading=noheader]
        \end{bibhyphenation}
    }
    {% split the bibliography using the predefined categories:
        \printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title={#2}]
        \begin{bibhyphenation}
        \printbibliography[filter=literature,heading=subbibintoc,title={\@bibtitleLiteratur}]
        \printbibliography[filter=avmedia,heading=subbibintoc,title={\@bibtitleAvmedia}]
        \printbibliography[filter=online,heading=subbibintoc,title={\@bibtitleOnline}]
        \end{bibhyphenation}
    }%
```

// Section 2

I did a backup of the whole directory thus I compared the aux file and had a look in to the .log and .blg file.

// .aux files
/ old - correct .aux file

```
\@writefile{lot}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{lot}
{\select@language{ngerman}}
\@input{cha1einleitung.aux}
\@input{cha1performanceMgt.aux}
\citation{MarStraPerfMgt}
\citation{MarStraPerfMgt}
\citation{ReiMktPerfMgt}
\citation{SchEntImpPerfMgt}
[...]
\abx@aux@number{140}{SchStratProjMgt}{0}{1}
\abx@aux@number{141}{ArmPerfMgt}{0}{2}
\abx@aux@number{142}{BarBSC}{0}{3}
```

/ new .aux file

```
\@writefile{lot}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{lot}   
{\select@language{ngerman}}
\@input{cha1einleitung.aux}
\HyPL@Entry{4<</S/D>>}
\abx@aux@cite{DilUntFuehrung}
\@input{cha1performanceMgt.aux}
\abx@aux@cite{MarStraPerfMgt}
\abx@aux@cite{ReiMktPerfMgt}
[...]
```

// new .log file shows the following message

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'MarStraPerfMgt' on page 4 undefined on input line 29.
```

// new .blg file shows this message

```
I found no \citation commands---while reading file cb_MainFile.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file cb_MainFile.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file cb_MainFile.aux
```

Citations in my document look like this:

```
\autocite[some text]{book1}
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile a very simple document with biblatex references, only to check whether the problem is in biblatex or in you complicated code?

Comment: test with [.tex](http://www.andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/bib.tex) and [.bib](http://www.andy-roberts.net/res/writing/latex/sample.bib),courtesy of http://www.andy-roberts.net/

Comment: Do you process the bib file with bibtex or biber. Newer versions of biblatex use biber as default backend.

Comment: As Guido says, the present version of `biblatex` uses Biber as default backend for generating the `.bbl` file; you probably are still using BibTeX. I don't know how to persuade Vim to call Biber, but you can do it from the command line: `biber filename` as usual

Comment: I compiled a sample doc (from texenthusiast) as tohecz advised. Worked fine. I think the reason for the error occured because the backend to biblatex changed as Guido supposed. This line changed to: \usepackage[style=numeric-comp,backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}[2011/05/12]    ----   I'm aware that I should vote for comments and answers but although I'm registered it is not possible.

Comment: This question should have not been closed.